# Minimum Euclidean distance between two points in an array of points

Tags: algorithm, geometry

The obvious O(N^2) is to calculate the Euclidean distance between each pair of points. I've implemented in Python (calc_euclidean_dist() implementation is omitted):

```
def closestPointPair(pairs):

    min_dist = sys.maxsize

    for i in range(len(pairs)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(pairs)):
            dist = calc_euclidean_dist(pairs[i], pairs[j])
            if dist < min_dist:
                min_dist = dist

    return min_dist
```

Is there a better solution? Maybe ordering the points?

Comment: Since distance between points **a** and **b** the same as between **b** and **a** - do not calculate the same value twice. It will bring you to `O(n Log n)`.

Comment: Some pointers at [Closest pair of points problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem).

Comment: @PM77-1 Indeed dist(a,b)=dist(b,a) and the inner loop just needs to iterate between list indices i+1 and N-1. I have updated the code in my question with this improvement. Nevertheless, the algorithm remains O(N^2), as the number of comparisons will be N-1 + N-2 + ... + 1 = sum(1,N-1) = (n^2-n)/2, which is O(N^2).

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 2):

The nearest point pair problem has a well-known solution (as pointed at by @dxiv). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem

Its time complexity is O(N log N) in the worst case and it is not too difficult to implement.